# How do you make a Post request with binary file in this situation?

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

i have System A (Web Interface for people to upload files) and System B (file archive system).

step 1) User submits a files via System A

step 2) System A receives the files ,and encrypt it

step 3) System A sends a Post request with the decrypted file by calling System B 's end point (http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bookstore/).

step 4) System B receives the POST request. then archive the file .

at this moment , i am stuck in step 3. i am abled to receive the files, but throw a exception when System A make a Post Request with the file

i am trying to post a csv file to http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bookstore/. However it return

- ```
    RestSharp.RestClient.Execute returned   "StatusCode: NotAcceptable, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)" RestSharp.RestResponse
  ```

Do you have any idea what wrong in below code?

```
string path = "THE PATH OF THE FILE";
byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string filevalue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(file);

var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bookstore/");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
request.AddParameter("text/csv", file , ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused, you have a `ValuesController` that expects an id but you do not use that but instead attempt to redirect to another controller to return a .csv?  The .csv would return as JSON or XML- otherwise you would just simply do a download for the file so it returns in the browser.

Comment: Hi Greg. Sorry to confused you.  in my situation. the controller will receive a file from view , and placed it in a folder. then i will redirect it to my another app 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/bookstore/.

i am stuck in making a post request. i have simulated the process in Postman ,
it has no problem there. that why i doubt that if i have missed something in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to redirect, should simply be:

```
public class BookstoreController : ApiController
{
     public void Get() => Download();
}

public static void Download()
{
     var client = new RestClient("...");
     var request = new RestRequest("...", Method.POST);
     var response = client.Execute(request);
     client.DownloadData(new RestRequest("/file", Method.GET)).SaveAs("filename.csv");
     
     Console.WriteLine("Output: ");
     Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

In essence, you could do the method content to download the file.  But create the client and request, then execute the response but download the data from the request into the response.  Then it should force the browser to download the file for the user.

Comment: Hi Greg.Thank you for your solution. it is nice. i shall tell you more information about the flow.

 i have System A (Web Interface for people to upload files) and System B (file archive system).

1) User submit a files via System A 
2) System A receive the files ,and encrypt it
3) System A will send a Post request with the decrypted file by calling System B 's end point
4) System B receive the POST request. then archive the file .


at this moment , i am stuck in step 3. i am abled to receive the files, but throw a exception when System A make a Post Request with the file.

Comment: Hi Greg. i have updated my code. i think that i didnt state my problem clearly.

Comment: So you cannot archive to the server, it fails?  What exactly does it say?

Comment: Hi Greg. Thank you . my problem is solved . 
i have checked the system

Answer (score 0):

Today i have checked the system Log . i found this message (which means my file is archived).

INFO 11:15:01.938 (FedoraLdp) GET resource 'bookstore/cc51bc52-e59a-4e29-801a-e7d979326197'

So that i  try to submit Post Request and check if file is archived .
and finally found that the file is archived as showed in system log. even though ,In the Http Post response ,it said that my Request is not acceptable ...

So that i think that The API End point does not return my a correct message and  not giving me a clear information about what is missing in Http Post Request i made.